# App Crash in SendMail execute

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, crash

I'm developing an app that send an email using the JavaMail API inside a fragment. The whole app is working just fine, but when I click on the button to send the email, the app crashes. I've tried to change the context in the SendMail code but it didn't solved my problem. I'm posting the Debug error that i'm getting and my Java code, if you need anything else, just ask me. Any help is really welcome.

**SendMail.Java**

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    //Declaring Variables

    private Context context;
    private Session session;

    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;

    //Progressdialog to show while sending email
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //Class Constructor
    public SendMail(OneFragment oneFragment, String email, String subject, String message) {
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = context;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Showing progress dialog while sending email
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Enviando mensagem","Aguarde um momento...",false,false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context,"Mensagem enviada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        //Configuring properties for gmail
        //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        //Creating a new session
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL,Config.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });

        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
            //Adding receiver
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject(subject);
            //Adding message
            mm.setText(message);

            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

**Error Debug**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: info.androidhive.materialtabs, PID: 6870
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:154)
                      at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:109)
                      at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
                      at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:110)
                      at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:104)
                      at info.androidhive.materialtabs.SendMail.onPreExecute(SendMail.java:50)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
                      at info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment.sendEmail(OneFragment.java:45)
                      at info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment.onClick(OneFragment.java:50)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

**OneFragment**

```
//More Code

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}


    private void sendEmail() {
        //Getting content for email
        String email = "myemail";
        String subject = "subject";
        String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();

        //Creating SendMail object
        SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

        //Executing sendmail to send email
        sm.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendEmail();
    }

//More Code
```

Comment: Have you tried diegoveloper answer?

Comment: Yes, that's done. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the constructor of your SendMail task

```
  //Class Constructor
    public SendMail(OneFragment oneFragment, String email, String subject, String message) {
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = context;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
    }
```

You are not receiving `context` value so the `context` is null :)

Then you have a problem here :

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Enviando mensagem","Aguarde um momento...",false,false);
```

**UPDATE : Fixing your code**

```
 //Class Constructor
    public SendMail(OneFragment oneFragment, String email, String subject, String message) {
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = oneFragment.getActivity();
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see it now... So how can I set the context value in this case?

Comment: That's it, thank you! I'm learning to code, so I'm having some difficulties, thanks for your time and attention.